# The meaning of though in the end of this sentence

Tags: meaning

I was reading the declaration that Michael Jackson´s daugther posted about her smoking cigarettes these past days, outside a restaurant. And she wrote a sentence like this:

"Sure as hell beats everything else in my past though".

I get that when she refers to " sure as hell beats everything else in my past", she means that the action of smoking isn´t the worst thing she has done in her life. But I would like to understand what "though"means in the end of the sentece of hers.

Thank you, folks.

Comment: It marks the utterance as contrasting somehow with what has gone before: "Despite its not being cool, it sure as hell beats everything else in my past."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be clearer in context but I suspect the conjunction sense is what is intended here.

> **though**
>   T͟Hō/Submit
>
> conjunction
>
> 1. despite the fact that; although.
>      "though they were speaking in undertones, Philip could hear them"
>
> adverb
>
> 1. however (indicating that a factor qualifies or imposes restrictions on what was said previously).
>      "I was hunting for work. Jobs were scarce though"
>
> synonyms:  nevertheless, nonetheless, even so, however, be that as it may, for all that, despite that, having said that; informal still and all
>   "it seems impossible, but you can try, though"
>
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=though&oq=though&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I really aprecciate your helping me.